# Garbage Collector no more references

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

I've been reading about GC in C# and I find some statements quite amusing to be real.

Say I have the following method:

```
public void Foo()
{
   Animal eAnimal = new Animal();
   eAnimal.Name = "Matthew";

   GC.Collect();

   ...more code not using eAnimal...

   return;
}
```

Supposedly in the *GC.Collect()* statement, the GC figures out that the memory address corresponding the the *new Animal()* object is not longer referenced in the code and thus is appropriate to dispose.

As far as I know, even in the *GC.Collect()* statement, there's a reference to the *new Animal()* in the stack (even maybe stored in some CPU registry). I know that if I inspect the code although that value exists in the stack, in the logic of the code is not longer used, but this kind of analysis I guess could be done in the compilation time and not really in runtime.

How does the GC knows that even if there's a reference in the stack to the heap, that reference it isn't gonna be used in any way in future statements of the program?.

My best guess is that the compilation takes this into account and creates appropriate instructions that cleans that reference in the stack and then makes the GC job more easy. But this seems to add a lot of overhead to the generated code.

Edit: I'm reading a book about the exam 70-483 and it states:

```
StreamWriter stream = File.CreateText(“temp.dat”);
stream.Write(“some data”);
GC.Collect()
```

> When running this piece of code in Release mode, the garbage collector will see that there
>   are no more references to stream, and it will free any memory associated with the Stream-
>   Writer instance.

Comment: But the way you describe is *the only* way it would work. What's so surprising about it?  Before the function returns, all of those references need to be "released" at some point. Why not do it before the call to `GC.Collect()`?

Comment: `Supposedly in the GC.Collect() statement, the GC figures out that the memory address corresponding the the new Animal() object is not longer referenced in the code and thus is appropriate to dispose.` According to whom?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, well, don't assume there's no code between Collect() and return. I'm gonna fix that in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning a reference to that object from your method, so when you call `GC.Collect()`, it looks at where the object is being used and sees that nothing else will reference it after the collection call.  As you indicated, none of the code after the call uses the object, so GC will safely dispose of it.

The [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does a fine job of explaining a similar situation to what you have.

A comprehensive explanation of garbage collection operation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx

Comment: In the MSDN example the stack of the called method has died so when the Collect() is called those references doesn't exist. In my example the current stack is still alive, so it isn't the same situation. My question is how it knows that the code after the call doesn't use that object.

Comment: @MatthewAzkimov It is same in a sense that you're not using your code after the collection call.  Why would GC not delete an object that is not being referenced in any way anymore?  This will be a good read for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx

Comment: I'm not saying it shouldn't. I'm asking how it knows that is not longer being referenced if in the stack of (I guess) still exists the memory reference to the memory address in the heap of the Animal object.

Comment: @MatthewAzkimov Check out a link in my update answer.  It's a very thorough explanation of how the garbage collector works.  Far more than can be posted here.

Comment: Their explanation is 'The list of active roots is maintained by the just-in-time (JIT) compiler and common language runtime, and is made accessible to the garbage collector's algorithm.'. I guess I'd have to ask Microsoft really 'how'....

Comment: @MatthewAzkimov Sorry, Matthew, that's as far as my knowledge goes on this subject matter.  If you could get a hold of Jon Skeet (http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), he probably knows.  See if you can email him through his website and cross your fingers that he's not too busy.